# How to remove a column from a 1D array matrix in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I am given a 1D array that has been printed as a matrix 3x3 and I am trying to create a new array that excludes the second column:

```
123
456
789

public void remCol(int clnum)
{

}
```

Comment: Array of what??

Comment: integers @shmosel

Comment: `Arrays.stream(arr).map(i -> i / 100 * 10 + i % 10).toArray()`

Comment: While this is very helpful I have to use a method to remove the column

Comment: Perfect, so put it in a method.

Comment: @molamk how is this a duplicate? have you read the question  and the proposed duplicate? This: how to **change content** of array; proposed: how to **remove** column and row of a 2D array

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution. My solution is dynamic thus the length of each element of your array can be different. Here is the code.

```
public class Main {

    static int[] array = new int[] { 123, 4565, 78910 };

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int clNum = 0;
        remCol(clNum);
        System.out.print("Input : " + clNum + " | Output : [");
        for (int j : array) {
            System.out.print(j + " , ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }

    public static void remCol(int clNum) {

        // checking if clNum is valid
        if (clNum <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        clNum--; // decrement clNum by 1 since array index starts at 0

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String value = String.valueOf(array[i]); // convert int to String for easy manipulation
            // checking if value is not null and not empty
            // checking if value has the column index of clNum
            if (value != null && !value.isEmpty() && clNum < value.length()) {
                value = value.substring(0, clNum) + value.substring(clNum + 1, value.length()); // remove the column
                array[i] = Integer.parseInt(value); // convert the String to int
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the output and results:

```
Input : 0 | Output : [123 , 4565 , 78910]
Input : 1 | Output : [23 , 565 , 8910]
Input : 2 | Output : [13 , 465 , 7910]
Input : 3 | Output : [12 , 455 , 7810]
Input : 4 | Output : [123 , 456 , 7890]
Input : 5 | Output : [123 , 4565 , 7891]
Input : 6 | Output : [123 , 4565 , 78910]
```